# Django model order the queryset based on booleanfield True/False that related with User FK profile

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have two django models as follows:

The first one is a user profile, which has a FK to User model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    PRF_user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='related_PRF_user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    PRF_Priority_Support = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

and the second is ticket model which has a FK to User model:

```
class ticket(models.Model):
    ticket_status_options = [
        ('open', 'open'),
        ('wait_customer_reply', 'wait_customer_reply'),
        ('replied_by_staff', 'replied_by_staff'),
        ('replied_by_customer', 'replied_by_customer'),
        ('solved', 'solved'),
    ]

    TKT_USER = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='TKT_USER', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    TKT_DEB = models.ForeignKey('Site_departments', related_name='related_ticket_department', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    TKT_SUB = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_index=True, verbose_name="ticket subject")
    TKT_BOD = models.TextField(verbose_name="ticket body")
    TKT_image_attachment = models.ImageField(upload_to='TKT_img_attachment', blank=True, null=True , default=None)
    TKT_CREATED_DATE = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    TKT_UPDATED_DATE = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I want to sort the tickets based on user profile `Priority_Support`:

If the user profile `PRF_Priority_Support` is True, I want to sort it first inside my views QuerySet, otherwise (if `PRF_Priority_Support` is False) I want to sort it normally.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should name your model starting with a capital letter.

And for ordering the tickets, you can use something like this:

```
 ' queryset_list = ticket.objects.order_by('-TKT_USER__related_PRF_user__PRF_Priority_Support')
```

In filtering, when you want to span relationships, you use double underscore __ .

More on this here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Another way is adding ordering to your model's Meta class.

For Example:

```
MyModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-my_boolean_field ',)
```

Comment: thank you mazhar ali, i followed your syntax and i make my qs ordering based on 'FK related name' like the following , ' queryset_list = ticket.objects.order_by('-TKT_USER__related_PRF_user__PRF_Priority_Support') '     and it's works fine

Comment: Yes, sorry i thought the priority attribute was user's.

Answer (score -1):

Hi you should filter as follow:

Model.objects.filter(field=True) or False depending on what you need

Regards

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, he didn't want to show only the True objects, he wanted to prioritize them first.